# How thirdparty android permissions works?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I wonder how some Android applications access thirdparty permission. For instance this app [MobileIron Go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileiron.anyware.android) ask for the following permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE android.permission.BLUETOOTH
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE android.permission.GET_TASKS
android.permission.INTERNET android.permission.READ_LOGS
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.MODIFY_VPN
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I have problems, from the android apps sandbox point of view, in understanding how this app is granted with 'com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.MODIFY_VPN' permission. Does it require to install 'com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android' app for proper working/functionality of [MobileIron Go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileiron.anyware.android)? I want to understand how an android app ask for permissions other than official permissions. Any pointer of some explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. My own app, which defined the permission for other apps to use, must be installed before other apps who want to use my permissions. Otherwise, those apps must be re-installed, to use my permissions. No other operations or codes are needed, just , the same as other system defined permissions.

And, several apps may define permissions with the same name, conflicting with each other. The first installed app occupies the conflicting permission name, others won't overwrite or change the original permission.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/app-permissions-work-care-android/

Comment: Thanks Akshay, can you name or provide link for your app? Is there any references for 'first app occupies the conflicting permission name, otherwise won't overwrite or change the original permission' in official Android documentation?

Comment: Moreover, could you kindly explain how thirdparty app can access permissions you are offering in your app?

Comment: see original answer (Akshay copied from here)  http://stackoverflow.com/users/429224/maratsafinwang